# What makes Date constructor accept momentjs object?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Why is this working? its not a instance of string or a number that a Date constructor accepts

```
var momentObj = moment()
var dateObj = new Date(momentObj);
```

I also wonder why calling the native `JSON.stringify(moment());` outputs a fine looking ISO string, without having to specify a transformer function as the second parameter

Comment: Because it implements [`toString()`](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.js#L1995) and `toJSON()`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be answered with a brief glimpse at the momentjs source.

Comment: well, i didn't know toString and toJSON would ever be called cuz i didn't know stringify and Date run toString() and toJSON so the source code wouldn't help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's `Date` can take a date string as parameter in the constructor.

> The string should be in a format recognized by the [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method ([IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) and also a version of [ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15))

Calling `moment().toString()` returns a date string in the format `Date` requires, which is what `JSON.stringify(moment())` does.

Comment: felt like i asked a newbie question. feels obvious now, that i know a custom toString is being called. i knew about acceptable string format, but didn't know toString would be called

Comment: You do now ;-) Thanks for accepting my answer!